# SIR model in Rstudio shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I´m trying to build the basic SIR model in Rstudio shiny. The model takes 2 parameters (beta = infection rate/day, gamma = recovery date/day), 3 initial values (S = numbers of susceptibles, I = infectious, R = recovered) and last variable is time (in days).

Here is the code of it just in R markdown:

```
library(deSolve)

sir_equations <- function(time, variables, parameters) {
  with(as.list(c(variables, parameters)), {
    dS <- -beta * I * S
    dI <-  beta * I * S - gamma * I
    dR <-  gamma * I
    return(list(c(dS, dI, dR)))
  })
}

parameters_values <- c(
  beta  = 0.05, # infectious rate/day
  gamma = 0.5    # recovery rate/day
)

initial_values <- c(
  S = 1000,  # susceptibles
  I =   1,  # infectious
  R =   0   # recovered (immune)
)

time_values <- seq(0, 10) #number of days (0-10)

sir_values_1 <- ode(
  y = initial_values,
  times = time_values,
  func = sir_equations,
  parms = parameters_values 
)

sir_values_1 <- as.data.frame(sir_values_1) # convert to data frame

with(sir_values_1, {
  plot(time, S, type = "l", col = "blue",
       xlab = "period (days)", ylab = "number of people")
  lines(time, I, col = "red")
  lines(time, R, col = "green")
})

legend("right", c("susceptibles", "infectious", "recovered"),
       col = c("blue", "red", "green"), lty = 1, bty = "n")
```

Now I want to add this into R shiny, where the user can input the beta, gamma and days value (sliderbar, or just input), then it will plot the result. I´m pretty new to R and tried some variations here, like putting the user input into ,,UI,, the calculating into ,,server,, then combine it in like this shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server). This code below I tried, but its not working. Can you guys help me, what I´m doing wrong, and what to follow to be able to put the code into R shiny?

```
library(deSolve)
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(




  sliderInput(inputId = "time_values", label = "Dny", value = 10, min = 1, max = 100),
  sliderInput(inputId = "beta", label ="Míra nákazy", value = 0.05, min = 0.00, max = 1, step = 0.01),
  sliderInput(inputId = "gamma", label ="Míra uzdravení", value = 0.5, min = 0.00, max = 1, step = 0.1),

  plotOutput("plot")
)



server <- function(input, output) {
  sir_equations <- function(time, variables, parameters) {
  with(as.list(c(variables, parameters)), {
    dS <- -beta * I * S
    dI <-  beta * I * S - gamma * I
    dR <-  gamma * I
    return(list(c(dS, dI, dR)))
  })
  }

  initial_values <- c(S = 1000, I = 1, R = 0)

  sir_values_1 <- ode(
  y = initial_values,
  times = time_values,
  func = sir_equations,
  parms = parameters_values 
)

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(rnorm(input$time_values))
    plot(rnorm(input$beta))
    plot(rnorm(input$gamma))
  })


}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thanks
Michal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is something like this you want?

```
library(deSolve)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput(inputId = "time_values", label = "Dny", value = 10, min = 1, max = 100),
  sliderInput(inputId = "beta", label ="Míra nákazy", value = 0.05, min = 0, max = 1, step = 0.01),
  sliderInput(inputId = "gamma", label ="Míra uzdravení", value = 0.5, min = 0, max = 1, step = 0.1),

  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  sir_equations <- function(time, variables, parameters) {
    with(as.list(c(variables, parameters)), {
      dS <- -beta * I * S
      dI <-  beta * I * S - gamma * I
      dR <-  gamma * I
      return(list(c(dS, dI, dR)))
    })
  }

  initial_values <-  c(S = 1000, I = 1, R = 0)

  sir_values_1 <- reactiveValues(val = data.frame())

  observe({
    sir_values_1$val <- as.data.frame(ode(
      y = initial_values,
      times = seq(0, input$time_values),
      func = sir_equations,
      parms = c(beta=input$beta, gamma=input$gamma) 
    ))
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    with(sir_values_1$val, {
    plot(sir_values_1$val$time, sir_values_1$val$S, type = "l", col = "blue",
         xlab = "period (days)", ylab = "number of people")
    lines(sir_values_1$val$time, sir_values_1$val$I, col = "red")
    lines(sir_values_1$val$time, sir_values_1$val$R, col = "green")
    legend("right", c("susceptibles", "infectious", "recovered"),
           col = c("blue", "red", "green"), lty = 1, bty = "n")
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: In addition, I would recommend to use more time steps, e.g. times = seq(0, input$time_values, length.out=500)

Answer (score 1):

Here another solution without the need of an observer function. More about deSolve and shiny at: https://tpetzoldt.github.io/deSolve-shiny/deSolve-shiny.html

```
library("deSolve")

sir_equations <- function(time, variables, parameters) {
  with(as.list(c(variables, parameters)), {
    dS <- -beta * I * S
    dI <-  beta * I * S - gamma * I
    dR <-  gamma * I
    return(list(c(dS, dI, dR)))
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput(inputId = "time_values", label = "Dny", value = 10, min = 1, max = 100),
  sliderInput(inputId = "beta", label ="Míra nákazy", value = 0.05, min = 0.00, max = 1, step = 0.01),
  sliderInput(inputId = "gamma", label ="Míra uzdravení", value = 0.5, min = 0.00, max = 1, step = 0.1),

  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    initial_values <- c(S = 1000, I = 1, R = 0)
    sir_values <- ode(
      y = initial_values,
      times = seq(0, input$time_values, length.out=1000),
      func = sir_equations,
      parms = c(beta=input$beta, gamma=input$gamma)
    )

    ## easiest is to use the deSolve plot function
    #plot(sir_values, mfrow=c(1,3))
    ## but you can also do it with own plot functions, e.g.:
    matplot(sir_values[,1], sir_values[,-1], type="l", xlab="time", ylab="S, I, R")
    legend("topright", col=1:3, lty=1:3, legend=c("S", "I", "R"))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the error:

> Warning: Error in ode: objet 'time_values' introuvable

In `ode()`, you should replace `time_values` by `input$time_values` and put the full `ode()` function in a reactive environment since you use some inputs:

```
  sir_values_1 <- reactive({
    ode(
    y = initial_values,
    times = input$time_values,
    func = sir_equations,
    parms = parameters_values 
  )
  })
```

Then you have some errors in your plot but setting `xlim` and `ylim` should make it work. However, if you want to display multiple plots, you must define several `plotOutput` and `renderPlot`. Putting three `plot` in one `renderPlot` will not display the three of them but only the last one.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply :), will check on that